# AWS Rekognition limitation on number of text chunks in response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rekognition

Trying to use the AWS Go SDK to do DetectText, basically trying it for OCR, and am seeing only about 30% of text being included in the response, and the rest of the text being ignored. Anyone aware of a limit on total number of text blobs being returned in the response? Any way to get around that?

Comment: I played with this tool recently and I haven't found any limit on the number of returned chunks in the response. Sometimes I don't receive an entry for a given text because the image is of bad quality and Rekognition isn't able to extract such text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS Recognition can detect upto 50 words in a single image only .

You should use an OCR software for large amount of data , such as free OCR

https://ocr.space/ocrapi

Now AWS textract service overcomes the limitations of rekognition, and provides OCR.

Comment: confirmed (it was actually on their doc, just towards the bottom of the page). 50 limit it is! thanks

Comment: Yes. There is a limit. I am not sure why AWS put such a hard limit. Possibly  AWS Textract is expected to fill the gap.